# How can I use numpy.correlate to do autocorrelation?

Tags: python, math, numpy, numerical-methods

I need to do auto-correlation of a set of numbers, which as I understand it is just the correlation of the set with itself.

I've tried it using numpy's correlate function, but I don't believe the result, as it almost always gives a vector where the first number is *not* the largest, as it ought to be.

So, this question is really two questions:

1. What exactly is [`numpy.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) doing?
2. How can I use it (or something else) to do auto-correlation?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269834/is-there-any-numpy-autocorrellation-function-with-standardized-output for information about normalized autocorrelation.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

To answer your first question, `numpy.correlate(a, v, mode)` is performing the convolution of `a` with the reverse of `v` and giving the results clipped by the specified mode. The [definition of convolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html), C(t)=∑ <sub>-∞ < i < ∞</sub>  a<sub>i</sub>v<sub>t+i</sub> where -∞ < t < ∞, allows for results from -∞ to ∞, but you obviously can't store an infinitely long array. So it has to be clipped, and that is where the mode comes in. There are 3 different modes: full, same, & valid:

- "full" mode returns results for every `t` where both `a` and `v` have some overlap.
- "same" mode returns a result with the same length as the shortest vector (`a` or `v`).
- "valid" mode returns results only when `a` and `v` completely overlap each other. The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) for `numpy.convolve` gives more detail on the modes.

For your second question, I think `numpy.correlate` *is* giving you the autocorrelation, it is just giving you a little more as well. The autocorrelation is used to find how similar a signal, or function, is to itself at a certain time difference. At a time difference of 0, the auto-correlation should be the highest because the signal is identical to itself, so you expected that the first element in the autocorrelation result array would be the greatest. However, the correlation is not starting at a time difference of 0. It starts at a negative time difference, closes to 0, and then goes positive. That is, you were expecting:

autocorrelation(a) = ∑ <sub>-∞ < i < ∞</sub>  a<sub>i</sub>v<sub>t+i</sub> where 0 <= t < ∞

But what you got was:

autocorrelation(a) = ∑ <sub>-∞ < i < ∞</sub>  a<sub>i</sub>v<sub>t+i</sub> where -∞ < t < ∞

What you need to do is take the last half of your correlation result, and that should be the autocorrelation you are looking for. A simple python function to do that would be:

```
def autocorr(x):
    result = numpy.correlate(x, x, mode='full')
    return result[result.size/2:]
```

You will, of course, need error checking to make sure that `x` is actually a 1-d array. Also, this explanation probably isn't the most mathematically rigorous. I've been throwing around infinities because the definition of convolution uses them, but that doesn't necessarily apply for autocorrelation. So, the theoretical portion of this explanation may be slightly wonky, but hopefully the practical results are helpful. [These](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Autocorrelation.html) [pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation) on autocorrelation are pretty helpful, and can give you a much better theoretical background if you don't mind wading through the notation and heavy concepts.

Comment: In current builds of numpy, the mode 'same' can be specified to achieve exactly what the A. Levy proposed. The body of the function could then read `return numpy.correlate(x, x, mode='same')`

Comment: @DavidZwicker but the resultings are different! `np.correlate(x,x,mode='full')[len(x)//2:] != np.correlate(x,x,mode='same')`. For example, `x = [1,2,3,1,2]; np.correlate(x,x,mode='full');` {`>>> array([ 2,  5, 11, 13, 19, 13, 11,  5,  2])`} `np.correlate(x,x,mode='same');` {`>>> array([11, 13, 19, 13, 11])`}. The correct one is: `np.correlate(x,x,mode='full')[len(x)-1:];` {`>>> array([19, 13, 11,  5,  2])`} see **the first item** is **the largest one**.

Comment: Note that this answer gives the unnormalized autocorrelation.

Comment: I think @Developer gives the correct slicing: `[len(x)-1:]` starts from the 0-lag. Because `full` mode gives a result size `2*len(x)-1`, A.Levy's `[result.size/2:]` is the same as `[len(x)-1:]`. It's better to make it an int though, like `[result.size//2:]`.

Comment: I found it must be an int, at least in python 3.7

Comment: @amcnabb what is unnormalized autocorrelation? Do you mean standardized? If so, the "unnormalized autocorrelation" you are referring to is called "autocovariance".

Answer (score 38):

Auto-correlation comes in two versions: statistical and convolution. They both do the same, except for a little detail: The statistical version is normalized to be on the interval [-1,1]. Here is an example of how you do the statistical one:

```
def acf(x, length=20):
    return numpy.array([1]+[numpy.corrcoef(x[:-i], x[i:])[0,1]  \
        for i in range(1, length)])
```

Comment: You want ``numpy.corrcoef[x:-i], x[i:])[0,1]`` in the second line as the return value of ``corrcoef`` is a 2x2 matrix

Comment: What's the difference between the statistical and the convolutional autocorrelations?

Comment: @DanielPendergast: The second sentence answers that: _**They both do the same, except for a little detail: The former [statistical] is normalized to be on the interval [-1,1]**_

Comment: @DanielsaysReinstateMonica Statistical Auto correlation means you can establish a statistical relation of the time series at a point of time to previous covariates, for example parametric ones like regression: $E(y_t|y_{t-k}) = fn(y_{t-k}, \beta)$ and $Var(y_t|y_{t-k}) = f(...) $ Since Expectation and Variance are inherently statistical quantities, thence the name. Convolution AC is typically used for Signal Processing for  say smoothing/filtering, for example, by using a convolving(sliding) window, say Sin wave, over your signal & literally multiplying and summing it at each point as you go.

Answer (score 28):

I think there are 2 things that add confusion to this topic:

1. statistical v.s. signal processing definition: as others have pointed out, in statistics we normalize auto-correlation into [-1,1].
2. partial v.s. non-partial mean/variance: when the timeseries shifts at a lag>0, their overlap size will always < original length. Do we use the mean and std of the original (non-partial), or always compute a new mean and std using the ever changing overlap (partial) makes a difference. (There's probably a formal term for this, but I'm gonna use "partial" for now).

I've created 5 functions that compute auto-correlation of a 1d array, with partial v.s. non-partial distinctions. Some use formula from statistics, some use correlate in the signal processing sense, which can also be done via FFT. But all results are auto-correlations in the **statistics** definition, so they illustrate how they are linked to each other. Code below:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def autocorr1(x,lags):
    '''numpy.corrcoef, partial'''

    corr=[1. if l==0 else numpy.corrcoef(x[l:],x[:-l])[0][1] for l in lags]
    return numpy.array(corr)

def autocorr2(x,lags):
    '''manualy compute, non partial'''

    mean=numpy.mean(x)
    var=numpy.var(x)
    xp=x-mean
    corr=[1. if l==0 else numpy.sum(xp[l:]*xp[:-l])/len(x)/var for l in lags]

    return numpy.array(corr)

def autocorr3(x,lags):
    '''fft, pad 0s, non partial'''

    n=len(x)
    # pad 0s to 2n-1
    ext_size=2*n-1
    # nearest power of 2
    fsize=2**numpy.ceil(numpy.log2(ext_size)).astype('int')

    xp=x-numpy.mean(x)
    var=numpy.var(x)

    # do fft and ifft
    cf=numpy.fft.fft(xp,fsize)
    sf=cf.conjugate()*cf
    corr=numpy.fft.ifft(sf).real
    corr=corr/var/n

    return corr[:len(lags)]

def autocorr4(x,lags):
    '''fft, don't pad 0s, non partial'''
    mean=x.mean()
    var=numpy.var(x)
    xp=x-mean

    cf=numpy.fft.fft(xp)
    sf=cf.conjugate()*cf
    corr=numpy.fft.ifft(sf).real/var/len(x)

    return corr[:len(lags)]

def autocorr5(x,lags):
    '''numpy.correlate, non partial'''
    mean=x.mean()
    var=numpy.var(x)
    xp=x-mean
    corr=numpy.correlate(xp,xp,'full')[len(x)-1:]/var/len(x)

    return corr[:len(lags)]


if __name__=='__main__':

    y=[28,28,26,19,16,24,26,24,24,29,29,27,31,26,38,23,13,14,28,19,19,\
            17,22,2,4,5,7,8,14,14,23]
    y=numpy.array(y).astype('float')

    lags=range(15)
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()

    for funcii, labelii in zip([autocorr1, autocorr2, autocorr3, autocorr4,
        autocorr5], ['np.corrcoef, partial', 'manual, non-partial',
            'fft, pad 0s, non-partial', 'fft, no padding, non-partial',
            'np.correlate, non-partial']):

        cii=funcii(y,lags)
        print(labelii)
        print(cii)
        ax.plot(lags,cii,label=labelii)

    ax.set_xlabel('lag')
    ax.set_ylabel('correlation coefficient')
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Here is the output figure:

[image]

We don't see all 5 lines because 3 of them overlap (at the purple). The overlaps are all non-partial auto-correlations. This is because computations from the signal processing methods (`np.correlate`, FFT) don't compute a different mean/std for each overlap.

Also note that the `fft, no padding, non-partial` (red line) result is different, because it didn't pad the timeseries with 0s before doing FFT, so it's circular FFT. I can't explain in detail why, that's what I learned from elsewhere.

Comment: Is there any way to perform your "partial" autocorrelation with an FFT based method?

Comment: @DanielWhettam I don't think so

Comment: Why wouldn't you divide by `len(x) - l` in autocorr2 instead of `len(x)` ? As it is now it would underestimate the correlation, right? Well, you'd say it's OK as long as `l << len(x)`, which is anyway a condition necessary for a robust estimation.

Comment: @Mahé `len(x)` is the "non partial" specification, so using the complete length.

Answer (score 27):

Use the [`numpy.corrcoef`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) function instead of [`numpy.correlate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) to calculate the statistical correlation for a lag of t:

```
def autocorr(x, t=1):
    return numpy.corrcoef(numpy.array([x[:-t], x[t:]]))
```

Comment: Doesn't "correlation coefficients" refer to the autocorrelation used in signal processing and not the autocorrelation used to in statistics? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Signal_processing

Comment: @DanielPendergast I'm not as familiar with signal processing.  From the numpy docs: "Return Pearson product-moment correlation coefficients.".  Is that the signal processing version?

Answer (score 12):

As I just ran into the same problem, I would like to share a few lines of code with you. In fact there are several rather similar posts about autocorrelation in stackoverflow by now. If you define the autocorrelation as `a(x, L) = sum(k=0,N-L-1)((xk-xbar)*(x(k+L)-xbar))/sum(k=0,N-1)((xk-xbar)**2)` [this is the definition given in IDL's a_correlate function and it agrees with what I see in answer 2 of question [#12269834](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269834/is-there-any-numpy-autocorrellation-function-with-standardized-output)], then the following seems to give the correct results:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some data
x = np.arange(0.,6.12,0.01)
y = np.sin(x)
# y = np.random.uniform(size=300)
yunbiased = y-np.mean(y)
ynorm = np.sum(yunbiased**2)
acor = np.correlate(yunbiased, yunbiased, "same")/ynorm
# use only second half
acor = acor[len(acor)/2:]

plt.plot(acor)
plt.show()
```

As you see I have tested this with a sin curve and a uniform random distribution, and both results look like I would expect them. Note that I used `mode="same"` instead of `mode="full"` as the others did.

Answer (score 12):

Your question 1 has been already extensively discussed in several excellent answers here.

I thought to share with you a few lines of code that allow you to compute the autocorrelation of a signal based only on the mathematical properties of the autocorrelation. That is, the autocorrelation may be computed in the following way:

1. subtract the mean from the signal and obtain an unbiased signal
2. compute the Fourier transform of the unbiased signal
3. compute the power spectral density of the signal, by taking the square norm of each value of the Fourier transform of the unbiased signal
4. compute the inverse Fourier transform of the power spectral density
5. normalize the inverse Fourier transform of the power spectral density by the sum of the squares of the unbiased signal, and take only half of the resulting vector

The code to do this is the following:

```
def autocorrelation (x) :
    """
    Compute the autocorrelation of the signal, based on the properties of the
    power spectral density of the signal.
    """
    xp = x-np.mean(x)
    f = np.fft.fft(xp)
    p = np.array([np.real(v)**2+np.imag(v)**2 for v in f])
    pi = np.fft.ifft(p)
    return np.real(pi)[:x.size/2]/np.sum(xp**2)
```

Comment: is it possible that there is something wrong with this? I can not match it's results with other auto correlation functions. The function looks similar but seems somewhat squished.

Comment: @pindakaas could you be more specific? please provide information on what are the discrepancies you find, with which functions.

Comment: Why not use `p = np.abs(f)`?

Comment: @dylnan That would give the _modules_ of the components of f, whereas there we want here a vector containing the _square modules_ of the components of f.

Comment: @dylnan yes it would have worked  but it would have unnecessarily calculated many square roots and then turned back to the square module.

Comment: Yeah, but did you realize that doing list comprehension is probably even slower.

Comment: Your result is (roughly) equivalent to `numpy.correlate(x, x, mode='same')`, but what about the full function `numpy.correlate(x, x, mode='full')? Can we get this using FFT as well?

Comment: BTW: `np.abs(f)**2` is way faster then the list comprehension. In principle, avoiding the unnecessary squares by using `f.real**2 + f.imag**2` is even faster, but the effect is negligible here because FFT is of course slower than some basic muliplication/addition.

Comment: Why is it good to demean and work with unbiased data?

Answer (score 10):

An alternative to numpy.correlate is available in [statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf()](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html). This yields a continuously decreasing autocorrelation function like the one described by OP. Implementing it is fairly simple:

```
from statsmodels.tsa import stattools
# x = 1-D array
# Yield normalized autocorrelation function of number lags
autocorr = stattools.acf( x )

# Get autocorrelation coefficient at lag = 1
autocorr_coeff = autocorr[1]
```

The default behavior is to stop at 40 nlags, but this can be adjusted with the `nlag=` option for your specific application. There is a citation at the bottom of the page for the [statistics behind the function](https://www.jstor.org/stable/25049287?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents).

Answer (score 4):

I'm a computational biologist, and when I had to compute the auto/cross-correlations between couples of time series of stochastic processes I realized that `np.correlate` was not doing the job I needed.

Indeed, what seems to be missing from `np.correlate` is the ***averaging over all the possible couples of time points*** at distance .

Here is how I defined a function doing what I needed:

```
def autocross(x, y):
    c = np.correlate(x, y, "same")
    v = [c[i]/( len(x)-abs( i - (len(x)/2)  ) ) for i in range(len(c))]
    return v
```

It seems to me none of the previous answers cover this instance of auto/cross-correlation: hope this answer may be useful to somebody working on stochastic processes like me.

Comment: For those looking to use this answer, the last line could be sped up using NumPy: `N = len(x); v = c/(N - np.abs(np.arange(N) - N/2))`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution without pandas:

```
import numpy as np

def auto_corrcoef(x):
   return np.corrcoef(x[1:-1], x[2:])[0,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Fourier transformation and the convolution theorem

The time complexicity is   **N*log(N)**

```
def autocorr1(x):
    r2=np.fft.ifft(np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))**2).real
    return r2[:len(x)//2]
```

Here is a normalized and unbiased version, it is also   **N*log(N)**

```
def autocorr2(x):
    r2=np.fft.ifft(np.abs(np.fft.fft(x))**2).real
    c=(r2/x.shape-np.mean(x)**2)/np.std(x)**2
    return c[:len(x)//2]
```

The method provided by A. Levy works, but I tested it in my PC, its time complexicity seems to be **N*N**

```
def autocorr(x):
    result = numpy.correlate(x, x, mode='full')
    return result[result.size/2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

I use talib.CORREL for autocorrelation like this, I suspect you could do the same with other packages:

```
def autocorrelate(x, period):

    # x is a deep indicator array 
    # period of sample and slices of comparison

    # oldest data (period of input array) may be nan; remove it
    x = x[-np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(x)):]
    # subtract mean to normalize indicator
    x -= np.mean(x)
    # isolate the recent sample to be autocorrelated
    sample = x[-period:]
    # create slices of indicator data
    correls = []
    for n in range((len(x)-1), period, -1):
        alpha = period + n
        slices = (x[-alpha:])[:period]
        # compare each slice to the recent sample
        correls.append(ta.CORREL(slices, sample, period)[-1])
    # fill in zeros for sample overlap period of recent correlations    
    for n in range(period,0,-1):
        correls.append(0)
    # oldest data (autocorrelation period) will be nan; remove it
    correls = np.array(correls[-np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(correls)):])      

    return correls

# CORRELATION OF BEST FIT
# the highest value correlation    
max_value = np.max(correls)
# index of the best correlation
max_index = np.argmax(correls)
```

Answer (score 1):

To implement IDL's [a_correlate](https://www.l3harrisgeospatial.com/docs/a_correlate.html) function with numpy, you need to run `np.correlate` with `mode="full"` and add `n-1` to the `lag` array.

```
def a_correlate(y, lag):
    y = np.asarray(y)
    lag = np.asarray(lag)
    n = len(y)
    yunbiased = y - np.mean(y)
    ynorm = np.sum(yunbiased**2)
    r = np.correlate(yunbiased, yunbiased, "full") / ynorm
    return r[lag + (n - 1)]
```

Example (based on the example in the IDL documentation page linked above):

```
# Define an n-element sample population:
X = np.array([3.73, 3.67, 3.77, 3.83, 4.67, 5.87, 6.70, 6.97, 6.40, 5.57])
# Compute the autocorrelation of X for LAG = -3, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8:
lag = [-3, 0, 1, 3, 4, 8]
result = a_correlate(X, lag)
print(result)
# prints: [ 0.01461851  1.          0.81087925  0.01461851 -0.32527914 -0.15168379]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer to the OP's question is succinctly contained in this excerpt from the Numpy.correlate documentation:

```
mode : {'valid', 'same', 'full'}, optional
    Refer to the `convolve` docstring.  Note that the default
    is `valid`, unlike `convolve`, which uses `full`.
```

This implies that, when used with no 'mode' definition, the Numpy.correlate function will return a scalar, when given the same vector for its two input arguments (i.e. - when used to perform autocorrelation).

Answer (score 0):

Plot the statistical autocorrelation given a pandas datatime Series of returns:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_autocorr(returns, lags):
    autocorrelation = []
    for lag in range(lags+1):
        corr_lag = returns.corr(returns.shift(-lag)) 
        autocorrelation.append(corr_lag)
    plt.plot(range(lags+1), autocorrelation, '--o')
    plt.xticks(range(lags+1))
    return np.array(autocorrelation)
```

Comment: Why not use `autocorrelation_plot()` in this case? (cf. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357300/what-does-pandas-autocorrelation-graph-show)