# how to find periods from time series data in python

Tags: python, time-series, artificial-intelligence, signals, fft

I have time series data
[image]
[image]

How do I get period??

The first picture graph and first graph of second picture is same graph.
and ignore the second graph of second picture.
We wanted to get micro current when a person workout.

this chart is that a man push the sensor with his finger.

Because we didn't make a good sensor yet.

and My team tried to find not noisy data so that we made the data to 0 below 400. But we can return it to normal data.

It seems 7 similiar periods.

I have used

https://github.com/gsubramani/SignalRecognition
but this have an error. code did not work well

https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/seq2seq-signal-prediction

My computer have no gpu.. so I couldn't test it. It had errors

https://github.com/tbnsilveira/STFT_analysis/blob/master/STFT_sinusoidal_signal.ipynb

This don't seem to have how to get periods.

I use python.

Any helps would be helpful!! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the variable always go to zero between periods? I think we need more information.

Comment: Also, I see 8 clear periods in your picture after the noisy part at the beggining. We need to know the full criterion to define a period, before looking at math solutions.

Comment: @C-3PO No.. My team tried to find not noisy data so that we made the data variable to 0 above 400. We assumed that below 400 is noisy data. But we can return it to normal data.

Comment: I am thinking that maybe a simple `for-loop` would work, define a period as at least `n` number of consecutives samples above 400. Maybe allow `m` exceptions to drop below the threshold, and/or require `r` samples to separate periods.

Comment: @C-3PO I wanted to find criteria to define a period, A period should be like the 3rd period. It should be going up , go to peak and going down like when person work out.

Comment: A quite similar question here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59265603/how-to-find-period-of-signal-autocorrelation-vs-fast-fourier-transform-vs-power