# Find and extract repeating pattern in data or graph

Tags: graph, pattern-matching, fft, speech-recognition, data-analysis

I want to find repeating pattern in graph, for example in the figure shown below (plz. click on the link, I don't know why it is not displayed), green peaks are repeated at some fixed interval. Here frequency and height of peaks are more or less same, **but not exactly same**. Here height and frequency are not known, but they are almost same for given repeating pattern.

I have read about motifs and Fourier transformation, but it seems too mathematical. Is there any simpler approach to solve this problem.

[Click here for graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ytry6.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the periodicity in data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239544/how-to-find-the-periodicity-in-data)

Comment: Autocorrelation is the way to go