# Estimate Autocorrelation using Python

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing

I would like to perform Autocorrelation on the signal shown below. The time between two consecutive points is 2.5ms (or a repetition rate of 400Hz).

[image]

This is the equation for estimating autoacrrelation that I would like to use (Taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation, section Estimation):

[image]

What is the simplest method of finding the estimated autocorrelation of my data in python? Is there something similar to `numpy.correlate` that I can use?

Or should I just calculate the mean and variance?

---

Edit:

With help from [unutbu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190597/unutbu), I have written:

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as N
import pylab as P

fn = 'data.txt'
x = loadtxt(fn,unpack=True,usecols=[1])
time = loadtxt(fn,unpack=True,usecols=[0]) 

def estimated_autocorrelation(x):
    n = len(x)
    variance = x.var()
    x = x-x.mean()
    r = N.correlate(x, x, mode = 'full')[-n:]
    #assert N.allclose(r, N.array([(x[:n-k]*x[-(n-k):]).sum() for k in range(n)]))
    result = r/(variance*(N.arange(n, 0, -1)))
    return result

P.plot(time,estimated_autocorrelation(x))
P.xlabel('time (s)')
P.ylabel('autocorrelation')
P.show()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503325/autocorrelation-of-a-multidimensional-array-in-numpy

Comment: I wanted to speak more specifically about the estimated autocorrelation equation.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643699/how-can-i-use-numpy-correlate-to-do-autocorrelation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12269834/is-there-any-numpy-autocorrellation-function-with-standardized-output

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I don't think there is a NumPy function for this particular calculation. Here is how I would write it:

```
def estimated_autocorrelation(x):
    """
    http://stackoverflow.com/q/14297012/190597
    http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Estimation
    """
    n = len(x)
    variance = x.var()
    x = x-x.mean()
    r = np.correlate(x, x, mode = 'full')[-n:]
    assert np.allclose(r, np.array([(x[:n-k]*x[-(n-k):]).sum() for k in range(n)]))
    result = r/(variance*(np.arange(n, 0, -1)))
    return result
```

The assert statement is there to both check the calculation and to document its intent.

When you are confident this function is behaving as expected, you can comment-out the `assert` statement, or run your script with `python -O`. (The `-O` flag tells Python to ignore assert statements.)

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the only way to calculate this estimate of autocorrelation. Can this easily be used to find autocorrelation of data loaded using `x = loadtxt('fn.txt',unpack=True,usecols=[0])` and plotted `pylab.plot(autoCorr, t)`?

Comment: Yes, something like that should work. Perhaps try `pylab.plot(x, estimate_autocorrelation(x))`...

Comment: If the data is complex-valued, a conjugation should be added to the assertion `assert np.allclose(r, np.array([(x.conj()[:n-k]*x[-(n-k):]).sum() for k in range(n)]))`

Answer (score 17):

I took a part of code from pandas autocorrelation_plot() function. I checked the answers with R and the values are matching exactly.

```
import numpy
def acf(series):
    n = len(series)
    data = numpy.asarray(series)
    mean = numpy.mean(data)
    c0 = numpy.sum((data - mean) ** 2) / float(n)

    def r(h):
        acf_lag = ((data[:n - h] - mean) * (data[h:] - mean)).sum() / float(n) / c0
        return round(acf_lag, 3)
    x = numpy.arange(n) # Avoiding lag 0 calculation
    acf_coeffs = map(r, x)
    return acf_coeffs
```

Answer (score 12):

The statsmodels package adds a autocorrelation function that internally uses `np.correlate` (according to the `statsmodels` documentation).

See:
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf.html#statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf

Answer (score 8):

The method I wrote as of my latest edit is now faster than even `scipy.statstools.acf` with `fft=True` until the sample size gets very large.

**Error analysis** If you want to adjust for biases & get highly accurate error estimates: Look at my code [here](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/correlations/errors.py) which implements [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-lat/0306017.pdf) by Ulli Wolff *([or original by UW in `Matlab`](https://www.physik.hu-berlin.de/de/com/ALPHAsoft))*

### Functions Tested

- `a = correlatedData(n=10000)` is from a routine found [here](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/correlations/acorr.py)
- `gamma()` is from same place as `correlated_data()`
- `acorr()` is my function below
- `estimated_autocorrelation` is found in another answer
- `acf()` is from `from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf`

### Timings

```
%timeit a0, junk, junk = gamma(a, f=0)                            # puwr.py
%timeit a1 = [acorr(a, m, i) for i in range(l)]                   # my own
%timeit a2 = acf(a)                                               # statstools
%timeit a3 = estimated_autocorrelation(a)                         # numpy
%timeit a4 = acf(a, fft=True)                                     # stats FFT

## -- End pasted text --
100 loops, best of 3: 7.18 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.15 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 88.3 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 87.6 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.33 ms per loop
```

Edit... I checked again keeping `l=40` and changing `n=10000` to `n=200000` samples the FFT methods start to get a bit of traction and `statsmodels` fft implementation just edges it... (order is the same)

```
## -- End pasted text --
10 loops, best of 3: 86.2 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 69.5 ms per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 16.2 s per loop
1 loops, best of 3: 16.3 s per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 52.3 ms per loop
```

Edit 2: I changed my routine and re-tested vs. the FFT for `n=10000` and `n=20000`

```
a = correlatedData(n=200000); b=correlatedData(n=10000)
m = a.mean(); rng = np.arange(40); mb = b.mean()
%timeit a1 = map(lambda t:acorr(a, m, t), rng)
%timeit a1 = map(lambda t:acorr.acorr(b, mb, t), rng)
%timeit a4 = acf(a, fft=True)
%timeit a4 = acf(b, fft=True)

10 loops, best of 3: 73.3 ms per loop   # acorr below
100 loops, best of 3: 2.37 ms per loop  # acorr below
10 loops, best of 3: 79.2 ms per loop   # statstools with FFT
100 loops, best of 3: 2.69 ms per loop # statstools with FFT
```

### Implementation

```
def acorr(op_samples, mean, separation, norm = 1):
    """autocorrelation of a measured operator with optional normalisation
    the autocorrelation is measured over the 0th axis

    Required Inputs
        op_samples  :: np.ndarray :: the operator samples
        mean        :: float :: the mean of the operator
        separation  :: int :: the separation between HMC steps
        norm        :: float :: the autocorrelation with separation=0
    """
    return ((op_samples[:op_samples.size-separation] - mean)*(op_samples[separation:]- mean)).ravel().mean() / norm
```

**`4x` speedup** can be achieved below. You must be careful to only pass `op_samples=a.copy()` as it will modify the array `a` by `a-=mean` otherwise:

```
op_samples -= mean
return (op_samples[:op_samples.size-separation]*op_samples[separation:]).ravel().mean() / norm
```

### Sanity Check

[image]

### Example Error Analysis

This is a bit out of scope but I can't be bothered to redo the figure without the integrated autocorrelation time or integration window calculation. The autocorrelations with errors are clear in the bottom plot
[image]

Comment: your data samples are far too small how could this be faster then a fft method for large data sizes? You're comparing n^2 to nlogn here.

Comment: feel free to repeat - the code is all above. I do actually state the FFT routine becomes the faster method at very large `n` so I suspect you just scanned the first sentence. It is possible that the FFT method has a lot of python overhead and error checking each time it is called

Comment: Sorry it's just misleading to state it like that, your only calculating the correlation for 40 different timeshifts. Normally if you have a dataset of 200000 points the part that is interesting performance wise is to look at the correlation function of the whole time. In this case you're dealing with a number of operations on the order of 200000^2 while  a FFT method would do around 5*200000. By the way my naive implementation, which is basically identical to yours takes 18.1 ms per loop on identical inputs...

Comment: Firstly, thanks for taking the time to look at this - I use this code a lot so any improvements are more than welcome! The sample size decreases as you increase the correlation time so measuring *all time* isn't that helpful due to lack of samples at longer times. Can you clarify what method you're timing and benchmark it with another ? (Different machines etc) To clarify, I agree that FFT is faster at scale. However for a lot of everyday cases where the sample `n<10000` and we look at a small auto-correlation time (typical of financial data) this method seems quite good ?

Comment: I've edited the opening sentence as you're right that it implies my routine is quicker for all sample sizes, when it's just faster at a limit. It might be interesting to call the underlying c-func directly (avoiding the python overhead) from `statstools` and compare?

Comment: I don't really have an opinion on that. Two more things, first by using  .ravel() I am not shure that you achieve anything, and my adding a .mean() to it you divide by len(op_samples), just so you're aware of this it is not the factor 1/(n-k) from the definition OP gave. secondly if you replace (op_samples[:op_samples.size-separation]*op_samples[separation:]).ravel().mean() by np.dot(op_samples[:op_samples.size-separation],op_samples[separation:]) you get further speedups, as far as I can see that was the difference to my naive implementation of autocorrelation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155498/discussion-between-pindakaas-and-alexander-mcfarlane).

Comment: ^ will respond on chat tonight - corp firewall blocks chat I'm afraid

Comment: yep that was it just compare a = linspace(0,100,1000000): %timeit np.mean(a*a) to %timeit np.dot(a,a)/len(a), on my machine 44.4 ms vs 8.07 ms

Answer (score 2):

I found this got the expected results with just a slight change:

```
def estimated_autocorrelation(x):
    n = len(x)
    variance = x.var()
    x = x-x.mean()
    r = N.correlate(x, x, mode = 'full')
    result = r/(variance*n)
    return result
```

Testing against Excel's autocorrelation results.