# How to avoid map object error in this autocorrelation script

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, object, mapping

Hello I'd like to use this autocorrelation script, I found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20463466/8238271

```
import numpy
def acf(series):
    n = len(series)
    data = numpy.asarray(series)
    mean = numpy.mean(data)
    c0 = numpy.sum((data - mean) ** 2) / float(n)

    def r(h):
        acf_lag = ((data[:n - h] - mean) * (data[h:] - mean)).sum() / float(n) / c0
        return round(acf_lag, 3)
    x = numpy.arange(n) # Avoiding lag 0 calculation
    acf_coeffs = map(r, x)
    return acf_coeffs
```

I am using this numpy array:

```
a=numpy.array([1, 2, 3,7,2,5,1,6,7,2,1,1,1,6,7,2])
```

And I am calling this code like this:

```
z2=acf(a)
print (z2)
```

Then the terminal returns:

`<map object at 0x ....>` (not sure what the number is so better not write down here)

How can I call this function for autocorrelation lags 1,2,3,4 and such correctly?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you want a `list` returned instead.

To do that, change this line:

```
acf_coeffs = map(r, x)
```

To this:

```
acf_coeffs = list(map(r, x))
```

**Explanation:** The code you copied was probably written for Python 2. The `map` function was changed in Python 3 to return a `map` object instead of a `list`. Thus, you wrap it in a `list` call to get a `list`.

Comment: thanks, works fine, is is possible to call it as a numpy array instead of a list?