# Autocorrelation for non-stationary time series

Tags: python, time-series

I have implemented a function in python to compute the autocorrelation of a time series at a specific lag k. It is implemented under the assumption that some of the time series might not be stationary.
However I'm finding that for some of these I am getting values greater than 1, specially on the last lags. So I guess I must be getting wrong some calculation.

I am implementing the following:

[image]

Where for the terms corresponding to the lagged series I'm computing the mean and standart deviation from lag k onwards.

I have implemented the following code in python, which computes the autocorrelation for a specific lag k:

```
def custom_autocorrelation(x, lag = 12):
    n = len(x)
    std = x.std()
    mu = x.mean() 
    autocov = 0
    mu_lag = x[lag:].mean() 
    std_lag = x[lag:].std() 
    for j in range(n-lag):
        autocov += (x[j] - mu)*(x[j+lag] - mu_lag)
    autocorr = autocov/(std*std_lag*(n-lag))
    return autocorr
```

As an example I'm trying with the following sequence, for k = 12, an getting a coefficient of 1.03:

```
np.array([20623., 11041.,  5686.,  2167.,  2375.,  2057.,  3141.,   504.,
         152.,  6562.,  8199., 15103., 16632.,  7190.,  6987.,  2652.,
        1949.,  2223.,  1703.,  2163.,  1850.,  6932.,  5932., 13124.,
       14846.,  7850.,  4526.,  1277.,  1036.,  1500.,  1648.,  1384.,
        1446.,  3477.,  6818., 12446.,  9734.])
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Hi @AlexanderMcFarlane sorry if it does not seem too clear in some points. Let me know what doubts do you have about the problem formulation.

Comment: I think your problem is with the means and stdev: Do you have a source for the equation. I suspect your issue is a theoretical / conceptual one rather than coding

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Yes I think so too. I have compared with some python libraries by computing the unnormalized autocorrelation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Signal_processing) and the results are the same. So it must have to do with this

Comment: Yes @AlexanderMcFarlane http://itfeature.com/time-series-analysis-and-forecasting/autocorrelation-time-series-data

Comment: that doesn't seem to be the same equation?

Comment: No, I just rewrote it but it is the same

Comment: ok I think I see your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have simply wrote the equation down incorrectly. The following parts

```
std = x.std()
mu = x.mean()
```

are not in-line with the original paper. It seems that you require the

```
std = x[: n - lag].std()
mu = x[: n - lag].mean()
```

fixing this gives

```
In [221]: custom_autocorrelation(a, 12)
Out[221]: 0.9569497673729846
```

I have also taken some ideas from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38417250/4013571) of mine to greatly speed up the calculation

```
def modified_acorr(ts, lag):
    """An autocorrelation estimation as per
    http://itfeature.com/time-series-analysis-and-forecasting/autocorrelation-time-series-data

    Args:
        ts (np.ndarray): series
        lag (int): the lag

    Returns:
        float: The autocorrelation
    """
    return (
        (ts[:ts.size - lag] - ts[:ts.size - lag].mean()) *
        (ts[lag:] - ts[lag:].mean())
    ).ravel().mean() / (ts[lag:].std() * ts[:ts.size - lag].std())
```

Comparing a regular autocorrelation function we get similar answers

```
In [197]: modified_acorr(a, 12)
Out[197]: 0.9569497673729849

In [218]: acorr(a, a.mean(), 12) / acorr(a, a.mean(), 0)  # normalisation
Out[218]: 0.9201920561073853
```

Comment: Will look into it properly in a while, but from a quick look seemslike you're right :)

Comment: If it's what you are looking for then can you accept my answer and I'll know I got it right for you :)

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it! Thanks a lot @AlexanderMcFarlane