# Calculate autocorrelation as a function of lag in Python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, signal-processing, statsmodels

In python (+ pandas/numpy/scipy/statsmodels) Is there a function to return the autocorrelations wrt lag? Does anything like this exist ready made as a library function?

To avoid confusion, I want the following, just I don't want to plot it but I want it returned as a series (pd.Series or pd.DataFrame):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
s = pd.Series(np.sin(range(1,100))) + pd.Series(np.random.randn(99))
plot_acf(s)
```

Effectively, I want what `pd.Series.autocorr()` returns but I want a series rather than a scalar returned where the series contains the autocorrelation for various lags.

Edit:

One way to achieve the above is to do:

```
pd.Series([s.autocorr(i) for i in range(0,s.shape[0]-1)], index=range(0,s.shape[0]-1))
```

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-autocorrelation-partial-autocorrelation/

Comment: @Wen-Ben It only shows how to plot acf/pacf. Can't see any code to return the acf/pacf series.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297012/estimate-autocorrelation-using-python sry just copy the wrong page

Comment: @Wen-Ben I mean I can just use a list comprehension with pd.Series.autocorr() tbh, just thought there is something more sophisticated. OK, I'll write my own functions.

Comment: I have provided one method hope it is faster than your old lines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about the Statsmodels `acf` function?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

np.random.seed(1234)
s = pd.Series(np.sin(range(1,100))) + pd.Series(np.random.randn(99))
pd.Series(sm.tsa.acf(s, nlags=5))
```

yields

```
0    1.000000
1    0.033136
2   -0.124275
3   -0.396403
4   -0.248519
5    0.078170
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of speed up your own method `vectorize`

```
np.vectorize(s.autocorr)(np.arange(0,len(s)-1))
```