# autocorrelation matrix with order in Python

Tags: python, matrix, lpc, autocorrelation

I have a equation of autocorrelation matrix with lag needed for lpc analysis:

[image: (click to download image): r_{l}(m) =\sum_{n=0}^{N-1-m}{\overline{x}_{l}(n)\overline{x}_{l}(n+m)}, m=0,1,...p]

I wrote methods:

```
def autocorr_matrix(x,order):
    R = numpy.zeros((order, order))
    for i in range(0,order):
        for j in range(0,order):
            R[i,j] = autocorrelate(x, abs(i-j))
    return R
def autocorrelate(x,lag):
    return numpy.correlate(x[0:len(x)-lag],x[lag:len(x)])
```

is it correct solution? Anybody have idea how can i test results of these methods?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Estimate Autocorrelation using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14297012/estimate-autocorrelation-using-python)

Comment: thanks but no. At link as result is unlimited vector of autocorrelation. In my equation is matrix limited by order of lpc

Answer (score 1):

To test your results you can use two methods:

1- Create two sin signals with phase shift and see whether your code can measure the correlation or not.

2- Use some trustable libraries for correlation and check your results.
the library I'm using is 'statsmodel':
[statsmodel.org](https://www.statsmodels.org)

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import acf,ccf
```

acf is for autocorrelation and ccf is for cross-correlation.