# Matplotlib's acorr to plot one side only

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I am using Python's matplotlib [`acorr`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.acorr) to plot autocorrelations of time series, but the graph always includes the negative lags.

Since autocorrelation function is always even anyway, I would like to suppress the negative x-axis of the graph.

Is there a parameter I can pass to `acorr`?

Comment: You could use the `numpy.correlate`, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/643699/how-can-i-use-numpy-correlate-to-do-autocorrelation. Or, if you really insist on using `matplotlib`'s `acorr`, simply adjust the plot range.

Answer (score 0):

Using `plt.xlim([0,<whaterver is the highest value>])` worked for me. You can see original post from Diziet Asahi [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070555/matplotlib-autocorrelation-plotting-negative-lags)