# Matplotlib autocorrelation plotting negative lags

Tags: matplotlib

I am using matplotlib acorr function to plot autocrrrelation, but I don't want the negative lags. How can I prevent the negative lags from appearing in the plot?
https://pythontic.com/visualization/charts/autocorrelation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you simply adjust the limits of your x-axis to only show the positive values

```
plt.xlim([0,<whaterver is the highest value])
```