# How can I use a Pandas data structure to calculate autocorrelation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pandas

I have data in text files that I have successfully parsed into a MultiIndex pandas structure however I don't know if what I have will do what I want it to do.

What I have is a lot of time series data with many identifiers (indices).  I ultimately need to calculate auto correlation times and other time series statistics on each time series.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from pandas import Series, DataFrame, MultiIndex
...
data = Series(value, index=[smear, block, obser])
print data

print data.ix[('0.07','1','0')]
```

This produces output like this for the data structure:

```
0.07  0  0     1.5802561
         1    0.82228274
         2    0.70917131
         3    0.90707599
         4     0.8517223
         5    0.26346815
      1  0     1.8163109
         1     0.9972372
         2     1.0872181
         3     1.2459765
         4     1.1500478
         5    0.35668446
      2  0     2.0734421
         1     1.2863641
         2     1.4033583
...
0.34  2  3     1.9047537
         4     1.8193612
         5    0.77739654
      3  0     2.2757423
         1     1.5499509
         2     1.6623247
         3     1.8330889
         4     1.7484187
         5    0.72914635
      4  0     2.3269071
         1     1.7137621
         2     1.7359068
         3     1.9162268
         4     1.9714984
         5     1.2095218
Length: 32100
```

and the time series information I am interested in exists at a specified value of smear, block, obser.  Here an example is given of smear = 0.07, block = 1, obser = 0.  The right most column is my time series data.

```
0.07  1  0    1.8163109
         0    1.8191682
         0     1.816836
         0    1.8172168
         0    1.8169705
...
         0    1.8184542
         0    1.8170772
         0    1.8159326
         0    1.8161826
Length: 107
```

How do I reshape the data such that I can write functions that will calculate auto correlation times?

Comment: is there a reason you are not using ``read_csv``?

Comment: I am not familiar with read_csv, by its name I assume you need comma delimitated data.  I do not have comma delimitated data.  Data are text files with a lot of garbage in addition to the lines I care about.

Comment: actually `read_csv` "sniffs" the file for the delimiter, so you neverneed to specify nomatter how it is delimitated

Comment: @Jeff: is `read_csv` part of `matplotlib`?

Comment: It looks like it is part of pandas.

Comment: It is part of pandas!

Comment: Thank you for the read_csv suggestion.  I will look further into it once I solve this problem.

Comment: @RyanSaxe I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry i must have skimmed over where you set the index

Comment: smear, block, obser are equal length lists

Comment: Do you have a way to put the last column into a regular python list?

Comment: The values themselves are stored in an equal length list called 'value'.  The line

data = Series(value, index=[smear, block, obser])

creates the data structure out of the lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use the "values" component of your `data.ix(whatever)` object to get the raw array of the time series. Then use [`numpy.correlate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html) to calculate the autocorrelation, using the method described in the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/643699/789750) question.