# Compute autocorrelogram (correlogram) from a wave file?

Tags: python, audio, speech, spectrogram

How to compute autocorrelogram (correlogram) from a speech signal (as a wav file) in python? Is there any online code/library function available for that?

Comment: Check out this discussion on correlation plot (correlogram) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643699/how-can-i-use-numpy-correlate-to-do-autocorrelation