# Computing autocovariance function vector in NumPy without using np.correlate

Tags: arrays, numpy

I'm trying to create a program that uses the Hannan-Rissanen algorithm to compute the sample parameters for an ARMA(p, q) auto-regressive moving average stochastic process.

The main step I'm having difficulty with is calculating the autocovariance function of the time series.

The program should take in an n×1-dimensional column vector Y and compute a k×1-dimensional column vector γ^hat given by:

[acvf equation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP0uS.png)

where Ybar is the average of the elements of Y.

How can I compute the above sum efficiently? (obviously for loops would work, but I'm trying to get better at vectorized numpy operations) Since I'm using this as a learning experience, I would prefer not to use any numpy functions other than very basic ones like `np.sum` or `np.mean`.

The following previous similar question has been asked, but doesn't quite answer my question:

[Computing autocorrelation of vectors with numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48844295/computing-autocorrelation-of-vectors-with-numpy) (uses `np.correlate`)

(a few others suffer the same problem of using more advanced `numpy` functions, or aren't spitting out vectors as I wish to do here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to replace `np.correlate` (which I assume is the main difficulty; I'm also assuming you have no desire to hand code an fft):

```
def autocorr_direct(a, debug=False):
    n, _ = a.shape
    out = np.zeros((n+1, 2*n-1), a.dtype)
    out.reshape(-1)[:2*n*n].reshape(n, 2*n)[::-1, :n] = a*a.T
    if debug:
        print(out.reshape(-1)[:2*n*n].reshape(n, 2*n))
        print(out)
    return out.sum(0)
```

For example:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 1, 2, -1]]).T
>>> autocorr_direct(a, True)
[[-1 -1 -2  1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 2  2  4 -2  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  1  2 -1  0  0  0  0]
 [ 1  1  2 -1  0  0  0  0]]
[[-1 -1 -2  1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  2  2  4 -2  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  1  2 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1  1  2 -1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
array([-1,  1,  1,  7,  1,  1, -1])
>>> np.correlate(a[:, 0], a[:, 0], 'full')
array([-1,  1,  1,  7,  1,  1, -1])
```

Note the reshape trick that shears the square array `a[::-1]*a.T`.

Note 2; to get a column vector from a 1D vector `X` use `X[:, None]`.