# How can I detect periodicity using auto-correlation automatically?

Tags: python, pandas, confidence-interval, periodicity

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

y = np.sin(np.arange(1,6*3.14,0.1))
autocorrelation_plot(y)
plt.show()
```

And this is the output of the auto-correlation plot:

[auto-correlation plot of y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Enm.png)

I would like to figure out a way to classify whether the function is periodic or not automatically (without using the bare-eye to look at the autocorrelation plot). I read that it is related to the confidence interval which is the line shown in the attached plot, but still have doubt on what I should do with it to better decide. So is there an automated way for using auto-correlation to decide the perdiodicity of the data?

Though, this is my try for an automated way:

```
result = np.correlate(y, y, mode = "full")
ACF = result[np.round(result.size/2).astype(int):]
ACF = ACF/ACF[0]
acceptedVar = []
for i in range(len(ACF)):
    if ACF[i] > 0.05:
        acceptedVar = np.append(acceptedVar, ACF[i])

percent = len(acceptedVar)/len(ACF) * 100
```

I just made a threshold of 0.05 to detect the points for which the confidence interval is 95%. Don't know if this is right or wrong statistically and logically. I then see if percent is bigger than 95% for a periodic pattern. I'm not sure of that as well.

Credit to: the first answer to [How can I use numpy.correlate to do autocorrelation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643699/how-can-i-use-numpy-correlate-to-do-autocorrelation)

Comment: At the risk of sounding obvious, write some code if you want to determine periodicity.

Comment: Is the code posted not obvious? The problem is that I can't access the object returned from the autocorrelation_plot() function.

Comment: You are asking for automated way.

Comment: @Spinor8 Thank you. I just edited that to include my code of an automated way.

Answer (score 0):

To start, with e.g. `ax = autocorrelation_plot(y)` you can use `ax.lines[5].get_data()[1]` to use the values from the pandas autocorrelation function directly.

This may be a somewhat naïve solution, but say you are just looking for the first, most significant, periodicity, you could just grab the first index of the highest peak in the plot:

```
first_max = np.argmax(autocorr) + 1
```

Which gives you the lag for which autocorrelation is highest = the period of interest (in units of your data's sampling interval.)

Say you wanted the next most significant period:

```
second_max = np.argmax(autocorr[first_max:]) + first_max + 1
```

And so on and so forth...

To note: this wouldn't work as well if your data is not as regular and periodic as it seems to be from your autocorrelation plot.