# How can I obtain the same result as pandas.autocorr() by numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, correlation, autocorrelation

I need to use numpy functions to replace all Pandas functions, but the Pandas package did not explain well how `pd.autocorr()` is implemented.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A': np.random.random(20)})
x = df.rolling(5).apply(lambda x: x.autocorr(), raw=True).dropna()
y = []
for i in range(15):
  y.append( np.corrcoeff(df['A'][i:i+5],df['A'][i+1:i+6])[0,1] )
  # np.correlate(df['A'][i:i+5]-df['A'][i:i+5].mean(),df['A'][(1+i):(6+i)]-df['A'][(1+i):(6+i)].mean(),'valid')[0]
  # np.correlate(df['A'][i:i+5]-df['A'][i:i+5].mean(),np.flip(df['A'][(1+i):(6+i)])-df['A'][(1+i):(6+i)].mean(),'valid')[0]
```

The `pd.autocorr()` result is quite different from that of `np.corrcoef()` (I treid `np.correlate()` as well).
Is there any way I can use numpy only functions to achieve the same reulst as `pd.autocorr()`?

----------------- Example result added ----------------

```
df['A'] = [0.5314742325906894, 0.7424912257400176, 0.2895649008872213, 0.16967710120380175, 0.5157732179121193, 0.8733423106397956, 0.585705172096987, 0.1387299202733231, 0.18540514459343538, 0.13913104211564564, 0.736937228263526, 0.20944078980434988, 0.2826810751427198, 0.15055686873748197, 0.4159491505728884, 0.07600226975854041, 0.15279939462562298, 0.1405723553409276, 0.8372449734938123, 0.3314986851097367]

x = [0.010637545587524432, 0.03594106077726333, 0.40104877005219836, -0.009106549297130558, 0.4008385963492408, 0.7794761931857483, -0.4182779136016351, -0.2962696925038811, -0.4083361773384266, -0.5244693987698964, -0.5063605533618415, -0.9496936641021706, -0.5303040575891907, -0.42881675192105184, -0.3371366910961831, -0.036231529863559424]

y = [0.11823200733266746, 0.16166841984627847, 0.2033980627120384, 0.2861039403548347, 0.5239653859040245, 0.1602079943122044, -0.3920837265006942, -0.28176746883177917, -0.3604612671108854, -0.5347077109231272, -0.4702461092101919, -0.5287673078857449, -0.4501452367448014, -0.3538574959825232, -0.10013342594129321]
```

Comment: This is a great question. Do you have some test data to illustrate the difference? If so please add an example to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we check the doc of the [pandas.Series.autocorr](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.autocorr.html), if you call the function with default arguments, the `lag` is 1, which means you need to shift one element for calculating the correlation.

For example:

```
a = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.2, -0.05])
s = pd.Series(a)
```

gives you :

```
0.1035526330902407
```

With `np.corrcoef` you need to slice the array to two arrays shifted :

```
np.corrcoef(a[:-1], a[1:])[0, 1]
```

Which gives you same result:

```
0.1035526330902407
```

So in your case the codes should be like :

```
W = 5 # Window size
nrows = len(df) - W + 1 # number of elemnets after rolling
lag=1
y = []
for i in range(nrows):
    y.append(np.corrcoef(df['A'][i:i+W-lag],df['A'][i+lag:i+W])[0,1])
```

You will get same result as `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The `pd.autocorr()` computes the autocorrelation with a default `lag=1`.  This means that it computes the correlation between an array and an array shifted by 1.

Here are a couple of ways to compute:

### 1. Looping through and appending for each `np.corrcoef`

You almost had the correct answer, but you just needed to offset by the `lag=1` parameter:

```py
y = []
for i in range(16):
    y.append(np.corrcoef(df.A[i:i+5][:-1], df.A[i:i+5][1:])[0, 1])

# 3.66 ms ± 98.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The solution is a mix of your own working and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7981132/18571565) - which might give a bit more explanation for you.

### 2. Without loop, using `np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`

[`np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.21/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) allows you to create an array of the sliding window.  You can then slice this by the lag parameter and calculate the `np.corrcoef`, then take the diagonal output of the second half of the output array:

```py
window = 5
lag = 1

y = np.diagonal(
    np.corrcoef(
        np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.A, window)[:, :-lag],
        np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(df.A, window)[:, lag:])
    [len(df.A) - window + 1:])

# 174 µs ± 2.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

As can be seen from the timings, the second option is far faster - although the code and concepts are perhaps a little more abstract.

Comment: This solution does not work, unless you have 19 PiB RAM on your system, for a series with a few million rows, as it requires O(N^2) memory.